# Gensim iterating file from folder charmap codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, encoding

I am following [this Word2Vec tutorial](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/). I want to make a gensim model, and first thing I want to do is try this code :

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()

sentences = MySentences('wos_abstracts') # a memory-friendly iterator
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)
```

wos_abstracts is a folder which contained hundred files to create a model from. When I tried to run it, it returned error "'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8". I suppose, if it's right, this is related with unicode, so how to implement file reading as unicode based on above code? And if not, what should I add? Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE (THE ANSWER)**

```
for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname), encoding="utf8") as f:
        yield f.read()
```

Comment: You should show the full error stack you've received, to identify exactly the line(s)-of-code involved. You may also want to add debugging output to the `MySentences` class, to show the file and line-number involved: that would let you examine the file(s) triggering the problem to see what sort of characters they include. (And if those steps don't lead you to a solution yourself, adding those details here could help others guide you to a fixed approach.)

Comment: In your latest edit, you are opening the file 2 times. You do not need to open it again in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "codec can't decode byte 0x8" while reading a while?

This is a very common problem which has a very common solution. You did not mention the encoding while reading the file.

Try something like this while opening the file:

```
file = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname), encoding="utf8")
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, but how to insert this line according to above code, since I opened the list of files in folder by os module. I tried to add it as you can see on update, however it returns "join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'TextIOWrapper'"

Comment: I have updated the answer, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: "utf-8" is just an example of the most common encodings. It might be something else in your case.

Comment: Hi, it is finally working, I've given the update. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. In future, please categorize your problem in a better manner. Your question had nothing to do with gensim, but how you were reading the file.

Comment: The better questions you write, the better and quick answers you get.